# imagick installation issues on the lion

Tags: php, mamp, imagick, magickwand

Currently i'm having issues with installing imagick correctly on the mac lion with MAMP.

I have ImageMagick-6.7.3 successfully installed.  I've tested out the calls on command line.  Note: The bin folder of the ImageMagick-6.7.3 has Magick-config, MagickWand-config, and Wand-config

I'm trying to install imagick-3.2.0RC1 which "Provides a wrapper to the ImageMagick library."  However, this is where I have the problem.  Without this installed, My php script won't execute and won't' know what how to use Imagick is.

I've tried 
1) sudo pecl install magick

output:

```
downloading imagick-3.0.1.tgz ...
Starting to download imagick-3.0.1.tgz (93,920 bytes)
.....................done: 93,920 bytes
13 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
Please provide the prefix of Imagemagick installation [autodetect] : 
building in /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootEzaTTE/imagick-3.0.1
running: /private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/configure --with-imagick
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin11.2.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin11.2.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin11.2.0
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking if awk is broken... no
checking whether to enable the imagick extension... yes, shared
checking whether to enable the imagick GraphicsMagick backend... no
checking ImageMagick MagickWand API configuration program... configure: error: not found. Please provide a path to MagickWand-config or Wand-config program.
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/configure --with-imagick' failed
```

As you can see, it complains about not finding the MagickWand-config.

However, I'm pretty sure the path to the MagickWand-config is correct.  I opened a terminal and typed

```
acBook-Pro:imagick-3.1.0RC1 $ Wand-config --version
6.7.3 Q16
```

If it wasn't set the the environmental path then that should have never worked.

I also printed out the $PATH:

```
-bash: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Users/darewreck/Downloads/MAMP_components_2.0.2/mysql-5.5.9/include:/Applications/ImageMagick-6.7.3/bin:/usr/X11/bin: No such file or directory
```

Update:
I installed homebrew and was able to do the following:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

This allowed me to call "pecl install imagick" successfully.

The issue i get next is when i call make:

```
-MacBook-Pro:imagick-2.2.2 darewreck$ make
/bin/sh /Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/include -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/main -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c -o imagick_class.lo 
mkdir .libs
 cc -I. -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/include -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/main -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/imagick_class.o
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_getimagematte’:
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c:262: warning: ‘MagickGetImageMatte’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:82)
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_paintfloodfillimage’:
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c:1035: warning: ‘MagickPaintFloodfillImage’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:101)
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c:1038: warning: ‘MagickPaintFloodfillImage’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:101)
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_clippathimage’:
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c:2319: warning: ‘MagickClipPathImage’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:74)
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_colorfloodfillimage’:
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c:2382: warning: ‘MagickColorFloodfillImage’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:77)
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_mapimage’:
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c:2772: warning: ‘MagickMapImage’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:87)
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_mattefloodfillimage’:
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c:2805: warning: ‘MagickMatteFloodfillImage’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:90)
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_medianfilterimage’:
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c:2832: warning: ‘MagickMedianFilterImage’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick/wand/magick-image.h:212)
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_paintopaqueimage’:
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c:2895: warning: ‘MagickPaintOpaqueImageChannel’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:106)
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_painttransparentimage’:
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c:2954: warning: ‘MagickPaintTransparentImage’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:108)
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_reducenoiseimage’:
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c:3097: warning: ‘MagickReduceNoiseImage’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick/wand/magick-image.h:260)
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_getimageattribute’:
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c:4080: warning: ‘MagickGetImageAttribute’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:60)
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_getimagechannelextrema’:
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c:4253: warning: ‘MagickGetImageChannelExtrema’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:79)
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_getimageextrema’:
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c:4482: warning: ‘MagickGetImageExtrema’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:81)
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_getimageindex’:
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c:5196: warning: ‘MagickGetImageIndex’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:65)
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_setimageindex’:
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c:5221: warning: ‘MagickSetImageIndex’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:114)
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_getimagesize’:
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c:5291: warning: ‘MagickGetImageSize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:140)
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_setimageattribute’:
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c:5599: warning: ‘MagickSetImageAttribute’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:112)
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_flattenimages’:
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c:5839: warning: ‘MagickFlattenImages’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:132)
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_averageimages’:
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c:6859: warning: ‘MagickAverageImages’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:131)
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagick_mosaicimages’:
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_class.c:7283: warning: ‘MagickMosaicImages’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:135)
/bin/sh /Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/include -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/main -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagickdraw_class.c -o imagickdraw_class.lo 
 cc -I. -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/include -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/main -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagickdraw_class.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/imagickdraw_class.o
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagickdraw_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagickdraw_setfillalpha’:
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagickdraw_class.c:253: warning: ‘DrawSetFillAlpha’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:167)
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagickdraw_class.c: In function ‘zim_imagickdraw_setstrokealpha’:
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagickdraw_class.c:313: warning: ‘DrawSetStrokeAlpha’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:168)
/bin/sh /Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/include -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/main -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagickpixel_class.c -o imagickpixel_class.lo 
 cc -I. -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/include -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/main -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagickpixel_class.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/imagickpixel_class.o
/bin/sh /Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/include -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/main -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagickpixeliterator_class.c -o imagickpixeliterator_class.lo 
 cc -I. -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/include -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/main -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagickpixeliterator_class.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/imagickpixeliterator_class.o
/bin/sh /Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/include -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/main -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_helpers.c -o imagick_helpers.lo 
 cc -I. -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/include -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/main -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_helpers.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/imagick_helpers.o
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_helpers.c: In function ‘php_imagick_progress_monitor’:
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_helpers.c:44: warning: format ‘%ld’ expects type ‘long int’, but argument 4 has type ‘MagickOffsetType’
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_helpers.c:44: warning: format ‘%ld’ expects type ‘long int’, but argument 5 has type ‘MagickSizeType’
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_helpers.c:44: warning: format ‘%ld’ expects type ‘long int’, but argument 4 has type ‘MagickOffsetType’
/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick_helpers.c:44: warning: format ‘%ld’ expects type ‘long int’, but argument 5 has type ‘MagickSizeType’
/bin/sh /Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/include -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/main -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick.c -o imagick.lo 
 cc -I. -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/include -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/main -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/imagick.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/imagick.o
/bin/sh /Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/libtool --mode=link cc -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/include -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/main -I/Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/include/ImageMagick  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -o imagick.la -export-dynamic -avoid-version -prefer-pic -module -rpath /Users/darewreck/Downloads/imagick-2.2.2/imagick-2.2.2/modules  imagick_class.lo imagickdraw_class.lo imagickpixel_class.lo imagickpixeliterator_class.lo imagick_helpers.lo imagick.lo -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/lib -lMagickWand -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/lib -lMagickCore
cc ${wl}-flat_namespace ${wl}-undefined ${wl}suppress -o .libs/imagick.so -bundle  .libs/imagick_class.o .libs/imagickdraw_class.o .libs/imagickpixel_class.o .libs/imagickpixeliterator_class.o .libs/imagick_helpers.o .libs/imagick.o  -L/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/lib /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/lib/libMagickWand.dylib -L/usr/X11/lib /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/lib/libMagickCore.dylib  -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/lib
ld: file not found: /usr/local/lib/liblcms.1.0.19.dylib for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [imagick.la] Error 1
```

I read some thread saying the the version I have might have bugs, so i tried building imagick-2.2.2 and still no go.

Any advice Appreciated. 
Thanks,
D

Answer (score 11):

Use which to figure out where the wand binary is (usually /opt/local/):

```
$ which Wand-config
/opt/local/bin/Wand-config
```

Install imagick:

```
$ sudo pecl install imagick
```

When prompted for the Imagemagick path, provide the result that you got back as the path to Wand-config, *without* the bin/

```
Please provide the prefix of Imagemagick installation [autodetect] : /opt/local/
```

Make sure you add

```
extension=imagick.so
```

to your php.ini

Comment: Hello, I did exactly that and I still have the error :

`which Wand-config
/opt/local/bin/Wand-config` -> 

`./pecl install imagick` -> 

`Please provide the prefix of Imagemagick installation [autodetect] : /opt/local/` ->

`ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/configure --with-imagick=/opt/local/' failed`.

Do you see the error somewhere ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've run into the same problem and ended up also finding the fix. The short of it is that you need the following commands (I am using macports, btw):

```
# sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin `which MagickWand-config`
# sudo ln -s /opt/local/include/ImageMagick-6 /opt/local/include/ImageMagick
```

After that, a simple "**sudo pecl install imagick**" worked for me.

The reason for these changes is that looking at the code in the **.configure** file of the **imagick** package, it looks for the **MagickWand-config** binaries in the **/usr/bin** and  **/usr/local/bin** folders. Also, it looks for the header files in the **/opt/local/include/ImageMagick** folder, but MacPorts installs the header files of recent versions of ImageMagick on **/opt/local/include/ImageMagick-6**.

Looking at your problem description, I am not sure the php include files are being sourced from the right location. This is an entirely different problem, but to make sure you have the proper php include files being sources, you should do the following:

1. Download the source files for the proper version of php from http://www.php.net/get/php-5.X.X.tar.bz2/from/a/mirror. For the latest version of php5.3 supported by MAMP (at the time of writting, 5.3.20), use this: **http://www.php.net/get/php-5.3.20.tar.bz2/from/a/mirror**
2. Create a folder named **include** inside your **/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.X.X** folder. In our example:

   **sudo mkdir -p /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.20/include**
3. Untar the php source code into the new **include** folder. In our example:

   **cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.20/include**

   **sudo tar -jvxf ~/Downloads/php-5.3.20.tar.bz2**
4. Rename the php folder from **php-5.x.x** to just **php**. As so:

   **sudo mv php{-5.3.20,}**
5. Make sure that MAMP's php is called before OSX'. There are several ways to achieve this. An easy way that works for every profile is editing the **/etc/paths** file and making sure that a line like **/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.x.x/bin** precedes the line **/usr/local/bin**. In my case, that file looks like this:

   /opt/local/bin

   /opt/local/sbin

   /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.20/bin

   /usr/local/bin

   /usr/bin

   /bin

   /usr/sbin

   /sbin
6. Go inside the php folder and run **./configure**. As so:

   **cd php**

   **./configure**

After changing the **/etc/paths** file, you will need to close and re-open your terminal to get the new settings to apply.

Answer (score 1):

If all fails and you generally install cli related stuff you might want to consider using homebrew which is quite useful for this kind of stuff and works for most people. Check out its homepage https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew

Homebrew is the new macports which was the new fink. I highly recommend using it. You can even use it for mysql, php and apache installs.

Comment: I went that path.  However, now i Have issues with calling make.  I'll update my post with the issue.

Comment: try `brew doctor` and see what the output says.

Answer (score 1):

The following post helped me to resolve my installation of imagick with PECL on MAMP 2 and Lion http://thoomtech.com/post/8832473042/mamp-imagemagick-lion. Be sure to read the part 1 of the post about using the PECL installer included in MAMP. It’s straight-forward and worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

For those having issues with this read my post here:

http://delboy1978uk.wordpress.com/2013/04/29/install-imagemagick-and-imagick-on-mac-os-x-lion/

If you are on php 5.4 you also need to set as beta and back before and after, like so:

```
sudo pear config-set preferred_state beta

sudo pecl install imagick

sudo pear config-set preferred_state stable
```